# Extracting Core Data content from an iPhone onto a Laptop

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, extract, synchronization

I have written an application (intended only for my own use) that monitors Core Location Accuracy and logs this information to a simple Core Data model. Each time the application is launched it begins recording the data and saving it to a new Item within the Model. What are my options for getting this data out of the iPhone and onto my laptop in a format I can use (JSON or XML)? I would like to avoid having to send it to a server and keep things as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) and gab the coredata file directly from your device.